# Enterprise Application Display Name

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am running a command to get the equivalent display name of an Azure Enterprise Application Object ID however it is not working. Below is the powershell script that I am using.

$caller.caller = (Get-AzADApplication -ObjectId $caller.caller).DisplayName

Thank you in advance for the help.

[This is where I am getting the data to be converted to its display name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9vlT.png)

Comment: I tried below powershell script and it is also not working.

$caller.caller = $caller.caller.(Get-AzADApplication -ObjectId).DisplayName

Comment: Replace Get-AzADApplication  to Get-AzADServicePrincipal in your command

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and it's working fine***

Please use the below command to get enterprise application display name.

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId 279d67ab-fa63-461a-*********).DisplayName
```

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the Enterprise Application  displayname from JSON. The resource was deployed by an Enterprise Application however the caller value is the object id. What I am trying to achieve is to get the application display name without hard coding its object id. Please see below screenshot.